# Stepwise Generalised Linear Model

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, stepwise-regression

As a statistics student I am in search of R code for a GLM, which is calculated stepwise. So far, the best I've found is for a Poisson Regression, but I need to find a Gaussian version of this:

```
library(MASS)
poisreg = function(n, b1, y, x1, tolerence) {  # n is the number of iterations   
  x0 = rep(1, length(x1))   
  x  = cbind(x0, x1)  
  y  = as.matrix(y)  
  w  = matrix(0, nrow = (length(y)), ncol = (length(y)))  
  b0 = b1  
  result = b0
  for (i in 1:n) {  
    mu = exp(x %*% b0)     
    diag(w) = mu  
    eta = x %*% b0  
    z = eta + (y - mu) * (1/mu)   # dot product of (y - mu) & (1/mu)   
    xtwx = t(x) %*% w %*% x  
    xtwz = t(x) %*% w %*% z  
    b1 = solve(xtwx, xtwz)  
    if(sqrt(sum(b0 - b1)^2) > tolerence) (b0 <- b1)  
    result <- cbind(result,b1) # to get all the iterated values  
  }  
  result  
}
x1 <- c(-1,-1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1) # x1 is the explanatory variable 
y  <- c(2,3,6,7,8,9,10,12,15)  # y is the dependent variable
b1 = c(1,2) # initial value  
poisreg (10, b1, y, x1, .001)   # Nicely converge after 10 iterations  
glm(y~x1, family=poisson(link="log"))   # check your result with the R GLM program
```

I'd be very grateful for any help in searching for code like this that calculates Gaussian GLM. If y you're interested: my ultimate aim is to play about with the tolerances of the GLM so that the fitted model lies between specified upper and lower bounds.

Comment: This is confusing. Do you mean stepwise regression, as in fitting several different models to choose the best one, or do you mean stepping through each iteration in the fitting algorithm for a single model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're rolling your own code; stepwise regression is already available in R via the `step` function. This works with any specification of generalized linear model, including ordinary linear regression (which is what we usually call a Gaussian GLM).

From the `?step` examples:

```
lm1 <- lm(Fertility ~ ., data = swiss))
slm1 <- step(lm1)

# <...many lines of output...>

summary(slm1)

# Call:
# lm(formula = Fertility ~ Agriculture + Education + Catholic + 
#     Infant.Mortality, data = swiss)
#
# Residuals:
#      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -14.6765  -6.0522   0.7514   3.1664  16.1422 
#
# Coefficients:
#                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)      62.10131    9.60489   6.466 8.49e-08 ***
# Agriculture      -0.15462    0.06819  -2.267  0.02857 *  
# Education        -0.98026    0.14814  -6.617 5.14e-08 ***
# Catholic          0.12467    0.02889   4.315 9.50e-05 ***
# Infant.Mortality  1.07844    0.38187   2.824  0.00722 ** 
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#
# Residual standard error: 7.168 on 42 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.6993,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.6707 
# F-statistic: 24.42 on 4 and 42 DF,  p-value: 1.717e-10
```

---

On re-reading the question, maybe you're actually not asking about stepwise modelling at all.

If you *actually* want to ask, why don't we have an interative algorithm for Gaussian GLMs, the answer is *we don't need one!* The usual algorithm for fitting a GLM, iterative (re)weighted least squares, works by fitting least-squares regressions for specially weighted and transformed versions of the data. If your model has a Gaussian error and identity link, then the weights and transformations disappear, so IRLS reduces to standard least squares. Hence you don't need to do any iterations.